# iOS Different Actions for Different Local Notifications?

Tags: ios, uilocalnotification

My app has two different features that can each schedule a local notification.  They are both reminders, but for different things, and for different parts of the app.  Is there a way to schedule 2 different actions for these?  For example, clicking notification style 1 sends you to the first tab, clicking notification style 2 sends you to the 2nd tab?

Comment: @Neeku I'm just using standard method of `- (void)application:(UIApplication *)application
didReceiveLocalNotification:(UILocalNotification *)notification`  Other than that, I have nothing, just trying to even learn if it is possible to have 2 different local notifications do 2 very different things.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes this is possible, just add a custom [`NSDictionary`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSDictionary_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/c_ref/NSDictionary) to the [`UILocalNotification`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/iphone/Reference/UILocalNotification_Class/Reference/Reference.html) [`userinfo`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/iphone/Reference/UILocalNotification_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009565-CH1-SW10) property.

For example, add a type when you create the [`UILocalNotification`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/iphone/Reference/UILocalNotification_Class/Reference/Reference.html):

```
myLocalnotification.userInfo = @{@"type" : @"openTab1"};
```

Then in the `application:didReceiveLocalNotification:` you could do:

```
if ([notification.userInfo[@"type"] isEqualToString:@"openTab1"]) {
// Your code to open tab1
}
```

Answer (score 1):

`UILocalNotification`s supports the `userInfo` dictionary. You can add some information here to trigger the response you want. For instance you can create you own "action" dictionary:

```
@{ @"action" : @"open_tab_1"}
```

When you receive the notification you inspect the `userInfo` and check the action key and trigger the correct behavior by just checking the equality of 2 strings.